# Xcode: How to have target settings inherit from project

Tags: xcode

Our target settings were [inheriting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642738/47281) from the project settings.  We changed a target settings (break inheritance) but now want the target to start inheriting from the project again.  How can you do this?  Clearing out the target setting in question doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between clearing out the target setting (setting it to the empty string) and removing it. Assuming the target is selected and the specific build setting is selected (but not in edit mode), simply press Delete to remove the setting at that level.

Comment: Deleting will just switch to ExCode default-value, which in most cases is "`$(inherited)`", so, if you want to 100% ensure that it inherits, type `$(inherited)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `$(inherited)` tag, which can be used to inherit build settings from the project level to the target level.