# User-Defined Value `FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME` & `FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER` not inherit from Project Setting

Tags: xcode, flutter

Usually, `User-Defined` Value would inherited from Project setting as [xcode-how-to-have-target-settings-inherit-from-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102779/xcode-how-to-have-target-settings-inherit-from-project),

But I found that the `FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME` & `FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER` not the case. Their value in `Project` & `Target` are `independent`.

Is there some config I should change to apply them to be inherited ?

Comment: what if i want 2 flavors?

Answer (score 14):

Just change the version in `pubspec.yaml` and then in terminal `flutter build ios` and go to Xcode you will see the new version in build setting

Answer (score 9):

Basically it's because I miss the part of `version: 1.0.0+1` in file `pubspec.yaml`.

It's format is: "version: `FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME`+`FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER`"

1. Flutter will build a file `/ios/Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` with `FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME` & `FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER` base on `pubspec.yaml`.
2. Xcode will `inherit the value` in target setting & project setting `from this .xcconfig`;

So just update the version in `pubspec.yaml`, don't update it in `Project Setting` or `Target Setting` to avoid value `overwrite`.